# How to write integration/system test with Spring Boot to test service with repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have @Service in Spring Boot app which is parsing file and then storing it into DB using Spring Data JPA. I want to test this parsing with all logic of changing this mapping. So, for this I need to store mapping in DB in test.

```
@Service  
public class ParsingService {
    @Autowired
    private StoringInDBRepository storingInDBRepository;
}

@Repository
public interface StoringInDBRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, String> {
```

The problem is that during test with annotation @SpringBootTest I don't want to load the whole context, but only my ParsingService. 
When I writing :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ParsingService.class})
public class ParsingServiceTest{

    @Test
    public void someTest(){
    }
}
```

This test couldn't be initialized because I am not loading StoringInDBRepository in @SpringBootTest annotation. However I can do it, because StoringInDBRepository is an interface. Usage of @DataJpaTest according to javadoc will be correct only if I'm testing repository layer. Usage of @DataJpaTest and @SpringBootTest is not recommended.

How should I test such services? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can mock the repository bean

Comment: @akuma8 no, because then they won't work as expected.and I need to real object will functionality. not mocks

Comment: I have the same problem but with a bigger scale. I have 4 services and a repository coming together the 5th service. I want them tested without any mocking. I want to see the real working of them and keep them under test. I'm a bit disappointed Spring doesn't provide a good solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after all investigations I found a couple solutions. I chose to enable repositories and service with

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ParsingService.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.my.repository")
@EntityScan("com.my.entity")
@AutoConfigureDataJpa
```

This is a workaround. And I don't think it is the best. The other solution is to create a @TestConfiguration which will return your service and all to use @DataJpaTest annotation to enable repository classes. In this case you should use @SpringBootTest annotation

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `@SpyBean` to get what you want. It is fairly easy to use.

**However** - You don't actually need to test it in that way. Because by having your application context tested, you are making sure all classes get injected/autowired as they should be. Then separately test the method on the service level with mocks. And lastly, use `@DataJpaTest` to test it in the repository/DB level.

So you decouple your tests nicely: integration tests / unit tests / repository tests

There is no need to tightly couple all those three things in one class or test method.

Comment: Well, that is not that solution I want. I want to test all component in couple and I have need to test it together. I also have docupled test. Thanks for your help)